# Next.js dynamic import with custom loading component: "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <em> in <div>."

Tags: next.js, dynamic-import

I have a next.js page with [dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import), which worked well until now,
but since I started using the [custom loading components](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-custom-loading-component) I get the warning

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <em> in <div>.
```

What can I do to avoid this warning ?

#### Here a reduced example:

```
// pages/index.tsx:

import React from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { LoadingComponent } from '../src/LoadingComponent';

// -- The custom loading fallback component
const loadingFallback = { loading: LoadingComponent };

// -- The dynamically loaded component
const DynamicallyLoadedComponent = dynamic(
    () => import('../src/DynamicallyLoadedComponent'),
    loadingFallback
);

// -- The main component
function Main(){
    return <DynamicallyLoadedComponent />;
}

export default Main;
```

```
// src/DynamicallyLoadedComponent.tsx:

export default function DynamicallyLoadedComponent(){
    return <div>ready loaded, final page content.</div>;
};
```

```
// src/LoadingComponent.tsx:

export const LoadingComponent = () => {
    return <em>... loading ...</em>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can not extract the part `{ loading: LoadingComponent }` into a variable, so it has to be written
inline, e.g.:

```
const DynamicallyLoadedComponent = dynamic(
  () => import('../src/DynamicallyLoadedComponent'),
  { loading: LoadingComponent }  // <-- needs to be written like this, a variable can't be used
);
```

Maybe this is because Next.js analyses the code in a kind of "pre-compiling" step and expects to find exactly this pattern (?).

Probably this is the same requirement as mentioned under [Basic usage](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#basic-usage) regarding the dynamic import itself:

> Note: In `import('path/to/component')`, the path must be explicitly written.
> It can't be a template string nor a variable.
> Furthermore the `import()` has to be inside the `dynamic()` call for Next.js to be able to match
> webpack bundles / module ids to the specific `dynamic()` call and preload them before rendering.
> `dynamic()` can't be used inside of React rendering as it needs to be marked in the top level
> of the module for preloading to work, similar to `React.lazy`.